# custom bean validation in java

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

i have been looking for a way to validate a bean for only certain properties instead of all the properties.

For Ex:

```
public Class TestA {

 @NotEmpty
 private String first;

 @NotEmpty
 @Size(min=3,max=80)
 private String second;

 //getters and setters

}
```

i have another class called 'TestB' which is referreing to Class 'TestA' as below

```
public Class TestB {

 @NotEmpty
 private String other;

 @Valid
 private TestA testA; 

 //public getters and setters
}
```

is it possible to write a custom annotation validator to validate only certain properties? something like below...

```
public Class TestB {

 @NotEmpty
 private String other;

 @CustomValid(properties={"second"})
 private TestA testA; 

 //public getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Use inheritance (interface and superclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groups` attribute to do that. It will looks like this:

```
public Class TestA {

 @NotEmpty(groups = {Second.class})
 private String first;

 @NotEmpty(groups = {Second.class})
 @Size(min=3,max=80, groups = {Second.class})
 private String second;

 //getters and setters

}
```

and

```
public Class TestB {

 @NotEmpty
 private String other;

 @Valid
 private TestA testA; 

 //public getters and setters
}
```

Where `Second` is an empty interface which defined somewhere.

For more details see examples in documentation: [2.3. Validating groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) Also, if you use Spring >= 3.1 you may be interesting in `@Validates` annotation which allows to enable validation of specified groups.